# my jquery datatable shows only round values in amount column , i want to have a values with currency format like $233.25 but it shows $234

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

My jQuery datatable shows only round values in the amount column, I want to have values with currency format like `$233.25` but it shows `$234`.

> HTML table head section:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>SalesNumber</th>
    <th>AmountExclGST</th>
    <th>GST</th>
    <th>TotalAmount</th>
    <th>ContactPerson</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>FullyPaid</th>
    <th>Attachment</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

> My javascript for columns:

```
{
  'data': 'AmountExclGST',
  'render': $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2, 'S$')
},
```

My result column :

```
      amount 
      S$234.00
```

correct format should be

```
      **Amount
      S$233.77**
```

Please advise me what should I do, in order to get currency format with decimal values ?

Comment: What is the original value?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
                {
                    'data': 'AmountExclGST',
                    'render': function ( data, type, row ) {
                        return parseFloat(data).toFixed(2);
                    }
                },
```

Comment: Thanks for the support siddhesh, but no changes in the result still its rounded the value

Comment: I am getting these data from my sql database and the datatype of the column is "Money"

Comment: Can you share query how you convert your result?

Comment: Sorry its my mistake, i found the solution, because in class i set the property of amount as an integer and that why its return integer value without decimal, but now i have changed the property as decimal . so now its returning correct value, there is nothing wrong in ajax calling method .. thanks for your support..